# How to use feeds module to import multi-value fields?

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I want to import a csv file using the feed module. This feed corresponds to an article content type, but the problem is the image field in the article content type contains multiple images. If I want to use the feed module to import, I can only import one image, if I paste multiple image urls, this causes errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) worked for me too. To get one row for each multi-value field I used the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function from MySQL. I used this in conjunction with the Feeds_SQL module.

Comment: +1 I've used Feeds Tamper for this and it's worked perfectly. Note if you want to import alt and/or title fields, then at the moment you'll need the patch from [#1080386](http://drupal.org/node/1080386)

Answer (score 2):

I just don't think Feeds supports multi value feeds that way.

I briefly considered [Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper), that is capable of making various manipulations to the indata, but I don't see how it could solve this particular problem.

I think your best bet, short of a big patch to feeds, is to override the Feeds Processor. I have an answer with an example of that here: [Using feeds module to import to user reference fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23831/using-feeds-module-to-import-to-user-reference-fields).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and installed the [Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) module. I then mapped my multi-value field in my custom importer and added a `Explode` plugin through the `Feeds Tamper UI`. The plugin will turn a comma separated list into an array.

Here's one row from my csv file:

```
GUID, title, image
1, "sample product", "images/image1.jpg, images/image2.jpg, images/image3.jpg"
```

This solved the problem and made it possible to connect more than one image to my multi-value field.

Answer (score 1):

Feeds Tamper solves this easily with the Explode plugin.

Comment: in my case this worked only without whitespaces and with `public://images` pointing to `/sites/default/files/images` where images where uploaded manually, say `public://images/file1.png,public://images/file2.png,public://images/file1.png` not just `file1.png, file2.png, file3.png`

Answer (score 1):

At first Explode didn't work for me. After trying several thing I tried to add a different string separator for the multi list. So, instead of a comma (,) I used a pipe (|) and the multi list came in on import for my nodes. I was using taxonomy and a term reference field.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [blog post](https://streamconsulting.nl/index.php?q=node/112) on how to import data from a multi row csv file into a CCK multigroup in Drupal. It involves the Feeds and Feeds Tamper module and a bit of VBA code. It could maybe give you some pointers.

Comment: The blog mentions 'We use CCK fields in a Content Multigroup to show this data in the invoice node' - What is a Content Multigroup? Is that the same as multifields?

Comment: the Content Multigroup was a part of the CCK3 module. It was available for Drupal 6. I don't know the equivalent for Drupal 7. You could take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection.

Answer (score 0):

This Blogpost did the trick for me:  [enter link description here](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper)
http://thejibe.com/blog/12/09/feeds-importing-multiple-values-one-multi-value-field

Maping multiple csv sources to one target field:

Source_01 > Target_Field
Source_02 > Target_Field
Source_03 > Target_Field

Then using Feeds Tamper to rewrite the Source_03:

Use REWRITE and as REPLACEMENT PATERN do:

Source_01, Source_03, Source_03

Then use a second plugin: EXPLODE. Make sure that the string separator is the same as the one you have used in the Rewrite plugin (,)